# Timestamp on embedded system : What rules?

Tags: logging, timestamp, embedded, system

I'm working on an embedded system that log temperature vs time.
Then, a smartphone application is supposed to retrieve those data.
The application, must of course, show the recorded time in a human readable manner, (day, hour:min:sec), in the smartphone's local time depending on being in Paris or Los Angeles for example.

In short, the smartphone application must take care of the adapted transformation.

From my point of view, the embedded system has to store the GMT timestamp, thus not taking into account any time zone or any winter/summer time changes, these last tasks (taking into account any time zone or any winter/summer time changes) being the smartphone application's job depending on it's own time zone and season.

Is there any rules or good practices about such implementation ?

I'm facing the case where I'm pretty sure the embedded system is locked on a modified GMT timestamp (+1 hour) (as I can access it with nRF Connect and read the raw data).

Comment: This is all very vague. To begin with, does your generic embedded system have a battery backup RTC?

Comment: No, no RTC. If the battery dies, the system loose track of time. Then, you need to install a new battery (20Ah rechargeable) and set the time with the smartphone's application developed specially for the device.

Comment: So how do you generate accurate time in the embedded system? Synchronizing it with the phone and running it from a TCXO?

Comment: There is no synchronizing, except the first time after you just powered the device with a new battery. Anyway, I would like to know what timestamp the system is supposed to hold for all country compatibility ? GMT or any other local or winter/summer time ? I'm still convinced it should hold GMT Unix timestamp. Then the smartphone's app should care to show the date in a Human Readable manner and considering smartphone's localisation or setup and winter/summer season if necessary !

Comment: All that information/clarification in your comment should be in the question.   You need to more clearly describe your system, or ask the question in such a way that it is independent of your system.  You seem especially vague how the time is set.  If you are developing the phone app why are you stuck with GMT+1?

Comment: The point is that the embedded software and the App phone are developed by 2 different companies. I'm trying to track some bugs and strange behaviour of the entire package, so I'm trying to dig in further and I need to understand how it's supposed to work. And I'm not a software or IT Engineer.

Answer (score 1):

The "best practice" is to use Unix epoch UTC time in seconds.

Although it is effectively the same, UTC is strictly what you want, not GMT.  GMT is a timezone designator, not a *time standard*.

Standard time handling functions that process Unix Time UTC and apply local TZ/DST adjustments are available in most languages and platforms. Moreover the C standard library you most likely have in your embedded system toolchain will most certainly use Unix epoch timebase so you have common concept of time across systems.

If for some bizarre reason the time the setting tool you have is hardcoded to UTC+1hr, then you should subtract 3600 seconds from the set value when the time is initialised.